# How to insert an constant horizontal line on a seaborn catplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to add a constant horizontal line on a seaborn catplot for all the subplots that was created - here is my codes :

```
sns.set()
fig = sns.catplot(x="LARGF", y="F_tot", hue="pass_inv", col="EPF", data=df_pi1_2_ag, kind="boxen", height=10, aspect=.7)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CGUM.png)

Comment: the generic (not seaborn specific) way to do this is to simply find the xlimits of the plot, and use that as your x coordinates to draw a line.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Could you please provide an MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

@zabop : here my MCEV:

```py
data = [[7,1800,2354,1],[7,1800,2352,2], [7,1800,2356,1],[7,1800,2357,2],\
        [8,1800,2554,1],[8,1800,2552,2], [8,1800,2556,1],[8,1800,2557,2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['EPF', 'LARGF','F_tot','pass_inv']) 
fig = sns.catplot(x="LARGF", y="F_tot", hue="pass_inv", col="EPF", data=df, kind="boxen", height=5, aspect=.7)
```

[image: output]

And I want to add a constant horizontal line at y=2500 on both graphics fromt the catplot (FacetGrid)

Comment: Please edit your question instead, not add it as an answer. An MCVE should not include any unneccessary information (is everything here really necessary?)

Comment: Most likely you will need:
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

[DO YOUR SEABORN STUFF HERE]

ax=plt.gca()

ax.axhline(y=heightofyourhorizontalline)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `refline`. See the docs for [refline](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.refline.html#seaborn.FacetGrid.refline). This can be found when looking at the [documentation for a FacetGrid object](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) which is returned by `sns.catplot`. There you can find further examples.

Here is the result for your minimal working example:
[image]

```py
sns.set_theme()
data = [[7,1800,2354,1],[7,1800,2352,2], [7,1800,2356,1],[7,1800,2357,2],\
        [8,1800,2554,1],[8,1800,2552,2], [8,1800,2556,1],[8,1800,2557,2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['EPF', 'LARGF','F_tot','pass_inv']) 
fig = sns.catplot(x="LARGF", y="F_tot", hue="pass_inv", col="EPF", data=df, kind="boxen", height=5, aspect=.7)
fig.refline(y=2500, color='red')
```